# Почему брошенное исключение в промисифицированной функций не обрабатывается блоком catch

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

```
doSomething=function () {
return new Promise(function (resolve,reject) {
    setTimeout(_=>{
        throw new Error ("error");
        resolve('resolve');

    },1000);
 });
doSomething().catch(err=>console.log(err.stack))
```

/usr/bin/node /media/arch/JavaScript/node/n5/promiseù.js
/media/arch/JavaScript/node/n5/promiseù.js:18
            throw new Error ("error");
            ^

Error: error
    at Timeout._ [as _onTimeout] (/media/arch/JavaScript/node/n5/promiseù.js:18:10)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:386:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:250:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:214:5)

Comment: А почему должно? `catch()` перехватывает вызов `reject()`, а не выброшенные исключения.

Comment: Без setTimeout будет ловить. Но ошибки, брошенные из асинхронных функций ловить не будет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> А почему должно? catch() перехватывает вызов reject(), а не
>   выброшенные исключения (c)Yaant

Нет, @tilin верно говорит. `catch` ловит только ошибки из тела промиса. Если хотите в таймере ловить ошибки, то заворачивайте асинхронную функцию в try/catch:

```
const doSomething = function () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(_ => {
            try {
                throw new Error("error");
                resolve('resolve');
            }
            catch (ex) {
                reject(ex);
            }
        }, 1000);
    });
};
```

Comment: "_`reject("error");`_" - нууууууу :( `reject(ex)` же.

Comment: Я именно концептуальный путь показываю. А что туда передавать - уже дело вторичное )

Answer (score 2):

Потому что он понятия не имеет, что таймаут как-то связан с промисом. Мало ли таймаутов мажет быть. Если есть необходимость в подобном коде, то стоит промисифицировать сам таймаут, а код выполнять в коллбеке промиса:

```js
function timeout(t) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, t));
}

function doSmth() {
  return timeout(1000).then(() => {
    throw new Error("error");
    return 'resolve';
  });
}

doSmth().catch(err => console.log(err.stack));
```

Comment: хотя и предостерегают от благодарности типа "Спасибо" , но не удержусь , так как нет больше отметить вашу помощь. Спасибо

Comment: @DimetrioRusso вы всегда можете переставить зеленую галочку на тот ответ который вам больше нравится

Comment: увы, увы. просто мне были полезны  два ответы